# Telerik RadComboBox drop down - change selection via code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

Going crazy with this. I have a Telerik RadComboBox drop down where I select an employee name. Next to it I have a regular text box where the user can type in an employee number instead (customer requested this). I have all the code written to have this work, but am missing the magical line of code that has the power to change the Telerik RadComboBox drop down selection via the code behind.

I've searched exhaustively for this and found a solution which should be able to select a new person by working on the drop down box object:

```
rdcEmployeename.Items.FindItemByValue(pID.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

This literally does nothing though, nothing happens... and yes I'm passing in valid values for pID. I am so lost and new to Telerik, can anyone help with how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the entire class behind the page:

```
    public partial class admTimeAllocationPage : BasePage
{
    public DataTable timeallocationdatatable;

    private static SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStr"].ToString());
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //string temp = Convert.ToString(Session["loginPersonID"]);       

        //   unlockCheckBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        //   unlockCheckBox.Text = "Unlock Checkbox";

        string strSkin = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Telerik.Skin"].ToString();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Pnladd.Visible = false;

            Persons GetEmployeeName = new Persons(sqlCon);

            DataTable dtpersonname = GetEmployeeName.GetAll_ID_And_NameEmployeesOnly();
            rdcEmployeename.DataSource = dtpersonname;
            rdcEmployeename.DataTextField = "PreferredName";
            rdcEmployeename.DataValueField = "ID";
            rdcEmployeename.DataBind();


            int PID = Convert.ToInt32(rdcEmployeename.SelectedValue);


            DataTable dtEmpnumber = GetEmployeeName.GetAllEmpNumber(PID);
            rdcEmpno.DataSource = dtEmpnumber;
            rdcEmpno.DataTextField = "employmentNumber";
            rdcEmpno.DataValueField = "id";
            rdcEmpno.DataBind();

            Employees Getdetail = new Employees(sqlCon);
            DataTable BindEmpDetails = Getdetail.GetDataFromEmployeeinfo(PID);
            Session["Idpass"] = PID;
            //RadGrid1.DataSource = BindEmpDetails;
            //RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DataSource = BindEmpDetails;

            DataTable Codebind = Getdetail.GetCode();
            Radcode.DataSource = Codebind;
            Radcode.DataTextField = "code";
            Radcode.DataBind();



            TimeAllocation GetTimeAllocationData = new TimeAllocation(sqlCon);
            DataTable BindTimeAllocationData = GetTimeAllocationData.GetCurrentDataFromTimeAllocationTable(PID);
            Session["Idpass"] = PID;
            RadGrid1.DataSource = BindTimeAllocationData;
            RadGrid1.MasterTableView.DataSource = BindTimeAllocationData;

            timeallocationdatatable = BindTimeAllocationData;


            EmployeeScheduledHours.Text = Convert.ToString(GetTimeAllocationData.GetEmployeeScheduledHours(PID));

            EmployeeAllocatedHours.Text = Convert.ToString(GetTimeAllocationData.GetEmployeeAllocatedHours(PID));

            UseTimeAllocation.Checked = getCheckBoxValue();

            UseTimeAllocation.Enabled = false;

            EmployeeNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(EmployeeNumberFromPersonID(PID));



        }
    }

    private int PersonIDFromEmployeeNumber(int employeeNumber)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStr"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmdselect = new SqlCommand(
            " SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Persons WHERE CONVERT(int,ADP_PersonID) = " + employeeNumber, connection);

            int pID;

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                pID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdselect.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                String strErr = err.Message;
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            return pID;
        }
    }

    private int EmployeeNumberFromPersonID(int personID)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStr"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmdselect = new SqlCommand(
            " SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(int,ADP_PersonID) FROM Persons WHERE id = " + personID, connection);

            int employeeNumber;

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                employeeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmdselect.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                String strErr = err.Message;
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            return employeeNumber;
        }
    }


    protected void btnEmployeeNumberLookup_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int employeeNumber=0;
        try
        {
            employeeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(EmployeeNumber.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            EmployeeNumber.Text = "Invalid Entry, Try Again";              
        }

        int pID = PersonIDFromEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber);

        unlockCheckBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        unlockCheckBox.Text = "Unlock Checkbox";


        if (pID != 0)
        {

            //I Want to change the selection HERE!!!!!!

            rdcEmployeename.ClearSelection(); 
            rdcEmployeename.SelectedValue = pID.ToString();


        }

        else
        {
            EmployeeNumber.Text = "Invalid Entry, Try Again"; 
        }



    }
    protected void rdcEmployeename_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        unlockCheckBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        unlockCheckBox.Text = "Unlock Checkbox";

        int PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(rdcEmployeename.SelectedValue);

        Persons GetPersonName = new Persons(sqlCon);
        DataTable dtEmpnumber = GetPersonName.GetAllEmpNumber(PersonID);
        rdcEmpno.DataSource = dtEmpnumber;
        rdcEmpno.DataTextField = "employmentNumber";
        rdcEmpno.DataValueField = "id";
        rdcEmpno.DataBind();
        Session["Idpass"] = PersonID;
        Employees Getdetail = new Employees(sqlCon);
        DataTable BindEmpDetails = Getdetail.GetDataFromEmployeeinfo(PersonID);

        TimeAllocation GetTimeAllocationData = new TimeAllocation(sqlCon);
        DataTable BindTimeAllocationData = GetTimeAllocationData.GetCurrentDataFromTimeAllocationTable(PersonID);

        timeallocationdatatable = BindTimeAllocationData;
        RadGrid1.DataSource = BindTimeAllocationData;
        RadGrid1.DataBind();
        EmployeeScheduledHours.Text = Convert.ToString(GetTimeAllocationData.GetEmployeeScheduledHours(PersonID));
        EmployeeAllocatedHours.Text = Convert.ToString(GetTimeAllocationData.GetEmployeeAllocatedHours(PersonID));

        UseTimeAllocation.Checked = getCheckBoxValue();
        UseTimeAllocation.Enabled = false;

        EmployeeNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(EmployeeNumberFromPersonID(PersonID));

    }
}
```

I'm new to stackoverflow so excuse the formatting. I'm trying to make the selected value for the drop down box change from 'btnEmployeeNumberLookup_Click'.

Comment: In the very last answer to the following post on the Telerik forum, someone suggests this code : `rdcEmployeename.ClearSelection();
rdcEmployeename.SelectedValue = pID.ToString();`. You can try it to see if it works for you. (Source: http://www.telerik.com/forums/combobox-selectedvalue-not-working)

Comment: The code you posted looks like it is c# codebehind.  If that is the case then the problem is most likely what event you put that code into.  You need to post more information about your event wiring and your codebehind or javascript such as it is.

Comment: replacing with  rdcEmployeename.ClearSelection(); rdcEmployeename.SelectedValue = pID.ToString(); did not work

Comment: Your code is probably fine.  You need to wire it up correctly is my guess.

Comment: Adam Heeg -- I've updated the question

Comment: I should mention I'm primarily a SQL guy, I'm just crawling painfully through this stuff which is mostly pre-existing code. So a simple answer is going to be the right one here haha.

Comment: Off the top of my head the basics look okay.  Did you set a breakpoint on your btnEmployeeNumberLookup_Click method and step through to see what is going on?  You said 'nothing happens'.  does that mean you can't reach a break point (no post back happens?).  Is there ajax on the page and update panels?  (going to bed now.  check back tomorrow)

Comment: Adam, If i put a breakpoint at "rdcEmployeename.ClearSelection(); rdcEmployeename.SelectedValue = pID.ToString();", it hits it, just changes nothing on the client web browser.

Comment: Everyone, I've solved this problem after 6 hours of tinkering. Turned out to be rather simple. The rad combo box's updates were controlled by a telerik rad ajax manager and updater rather than an update panel. I don't have experience in using these, so I threw out the rad ajax manager and went for a simple update panel...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the RadComboBox to the radAjaxManager:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>

    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rdcEmployeenameEmployeeNumber">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="EmployeeNumber"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```